# Should you care about truncation and padding in an LLM even if it has a very large tokenizer.max_length so that truncation will never happen?

Tags: huggingface, finetuning, llm, parameter

I want to find out the role of truncation and padding in Huggingface Transformers pretrained models and/or any fine-tuning models on top. Taking a large language model like the German GPT2 shows that the `max_length` is very large so that truncation should not play a role in the code - if I am not mistaken:

```py
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dbmdz/german-gpt2")
tokenizer.truncate_sequences
```

Out:

```shell
> <bound method PreTrainedTokenizerBase.truncate_sequences of
> PreTrainedTokenizerFast(name_or_path='dbmdz/german-gpt2',
> vocab_size=50265, model_max_len=1000000000000000019884624838656,
> is_fast=True, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right',
> special_tokens={'bos_token': '<|endoftext|>', 'eos_token':
> '<|endoftext|>', 'unk_token': '<|endoftext|>'})>
```

Checking only the `max_length`:

```py
tokenizer.model_max_length
```

Out:

```shell
1000000000000000019884624838656
```

We can see that the `max_length` is so utterly large that I doubt any full document will ever reach it - and this is just the length of each example, row by row, in the dataset. I guess that truncation does not play a role at all anymore if such a large `max_length` is set. "Set the truncation parameter to True to truncate a sequence to the maximum length accepted by the model" is what the Huggingface guide says about truncation, see [Truncation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/preprocessing#truncation).

That does not sound as if I ever can truncate the text or ever wanted to since that would lead to a worse understanding of the text. And that seems right since [Padding and truncation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/pad_truncation#padding-and-truncation) shows that:

> `False` or 'do_not_truncate': no truncation is applied. This is the default behavior.
> ...
> `False` or 'do_not_pad': no padding is applied. This is the default behavior.

The default for truncation is `False` anyway, why should I care about truncation? Should I care at all? If the `tokenizer.max_length` is so very very large, is truncation not just never happening anyway? Will the change to `True` change the output of the model or not?

Comment: That for sure is not the maximum allowed length. The original GPT-2 has a maximum length of 1024, and german-gpt2 is just a retraining of the original architecture on German text.

Comment: Also, from a memory perspective, it is unlikely that the quadratic memory needs of the Transformer's attention layers are going to be Ok with that number.

Comment: @noe I checked it again. The code above is all you need, and the `max_length` *is* that large. And I think it is since this number means the length of one example, and truncation is set to False by default, and the model training should just never drop any input text, therefore it is that large. The number is not about memory since text is read in batches.

Comment: That number is just the maximum representable integer at that precision. Just google it and see many other confused people asking about it.

Comment: You can probably check the actual maximum length in `model.config.max_position_embeddings`

Comment: @noe That gives `1024`. So they might drop a lot of text if it gets too long? But that would mean that I should care about truncation. And how do they do it that truncation is set to `False` if the max length of the model does not allow bigger examples? They split them up, without cutting any token in halves. If set to "True": "This will truncate token by token, removing a token from the longest sequence in the pair until the proper length is reached." I guess that too long text gets wrapped into many examples so that nothing of the text gets dropped.

Comment: @noe Then I should care about truncation. Setting the truncation to `True` might indeed change the output of the model. Your remarks can already make an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The large number you are seeing is not the maximum length, but the maximum representable integer at that precision. It's there because no maximum length has been set.

The original GPT-2 has a maximum length of 1024, and german-gpt2 is just a retraining of the original architecture on German text, so it should be the same. Anyway, you can make sure checking `model.config.max_position_embeddings`, which, as per you comments, is also 1024.

You should indeed care about the truncation. When training, usually you want to use as much text as possible, so normally you split very large text chunks into different samples.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, you need to care about truncation/padding/max numbers for your finet-tuning dataset

The question here is just about the max number, but since you need to care about how you steer the preprocessing, this linked question will help: [How can you get a Huggingface fine-tuning model with the Trainer class from your own text where you can set the arguments for truncation and padding?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126382/97556) for code and more insight.

Unless you load a pretrained dataset with Auto classes, you should care about such parameters. You should check if your text is fully tokenized by decoding the `input_ids` that you must have in the dataset. Also mind that the model has its own setup after the tokenizing which should outweigh the preprocessing setup. The preprocessing is just hand over the right input for the training. The model training reads and understand this input in its own way.

You need to care about truncation and the like during both preprocessing and training. Check samples and try understanding what is going on. I still do not know how the `eos_token` and `pad_token` come into play for the fine-tuning training and which arguments change what. The next chapter is only about the max numbers. I guess that changing the max number of tokens is not enough to steer the ship.

### Auto classes (of GPT2) and DistilBert: max numbers

This takes up the other answer and checks the max numbers of the tokenizer and model objects of two example models ("german-gpt2" and "distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad").

It shows that the AutoTokenizer is empty when it is loaded. That is why the `tokenizer.model_max_length` is the highest number you can get from the data type. It does not play any role, and that is why loading the model works at all. As long as you try loading it with the GPT2Tokenizer, it will fail to load, but if you load it with the empty AutoTokenizer instead, as the model card asks you to, it works. From this, I can see without any further reading that the model outweighs the settings of the tokenizer. Large text input will be split into blocks that the model allows, and it does not seem to play a role how the tokenizer itself is set up. One could say that the AutoTokenizer is the tokenizer of the model's settings.

The checks also show that you sometimes have to search for the right model max variable yourself since for the DistilBert model, the max number seems to be called `n_positions` in the "german-gpt2" config but `max_position_embeddings` in the "distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad" config, and yet, you can ask both models for `model.config.max_position_embeddings`.

```
model_name = "dbmdz/german-gpt2"
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

print(tokenizer.max_len_sentences_pair)
print(tokenizer.max_len_single_sentence)
print(tokenizer.max_model_input_sizes)
print(tokenizer.model_max_length)

1000000000000000019884624838656
1000000000000000019884624838656
{'gpt2': 1024, 'gpt2-medium': 1024, 'gpt2-large': 1024, 'gpt2-xl': 1024, 'distilgpt2': 1024}
1000000000000000019884624838656
```

But once you set the tokenizer with your own arguments, the output changes:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    model_name, eos_token="<|endoftext|>", pad_token="[PAD]", model_max_length=512)

print(tokenizer.max_len_sentences_pair)
print(tokenizer.max_len_single_sentence)
print(tokenizer.max_model_input_sizes)
print(tokenizer.model_max_length)

512
512
{'gpt2': 1024, 'gpt2-medium': 1024, 'gpt2-large': 1024, 'gpt2-xl': 1024, 'distilgpt2': 1024}
512
```

Yet, you do not seem to need the tokenizing at all since the model will tell in which blocks it will read the input.

```
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
model.config.max_position_embeddings
1024
```

Here is an insight into the max variables of DistilBert:

```
model_name = "distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad"
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

print(tokenizer.max_len_sentences_pair)
print(tokenizer.max_len_single_sentence)
print(tokenizer.max_model_input_sizes)
print(tokenizer.model_max_length)

from transformers import DistilBertModel

model = DistilBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
model.config.max_position_embeddings

509
510
{'distilbert-base-uncased': 512, 'distilbert-base-uncased-distilled-squad': 512, 'distilbert-base-cased': 512, 'distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad': 512, 'distilbert-base-german-cased': 512, 'distilbert-base-multilingual-cased': 512}
512
512
```

And if you check the `model.config`, you find these max variables, and `n_positions` should be the same as `max_position_embeddings`:

```
  "n_ctx": 1024,
  "n_embd": 768,
  ...
  "n_positions": 1024,
```

### Deep dive

Needed for the checks:

```
import inspect
```

#### Example 1: German GPT2 (with Autoclasses)

You have to import this model with [AutoClasses](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/auto), see the model card [Using the model](https://huggingface.co/dbmdz/german-gpt2#using-the-model). They do not ask you to enter any arguments for the AutoTokenizer object, and the class is empty but still works since the mode config outweighs the tokenizer settings.

##### AutoTokenizer

```
model_name = "dbmdz/german-gpt2"
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

```
inspect.signature(AutoTokenizer)
<Signature ()>
```

```
dir(AutoTokenizer)
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'from_pretrained',
 'register']
```

```
from transformers import AutoModel

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
model.config.max_position_embeddings
1024
```

```
dir(AutoModel)  
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_model_mapping',
 'from_config',
 'from_pretrained',
 'register']
```

##### GPT2Tokenizer

Even though this throws an error for the tokenizer of the german-gpt2 model, we can still check how its classes and parameters look like.

```
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer
inspect.signature(GPT2Tokenizer)
<Signature (vocab_file, merges_file, errors='replace', unk_token='<|endoftext|>', bos_token='<|endoftext|>', eos_token='<|endoftext|>', pad_token=None, add_prefix_space=False, add_bos_token=False, **kwargs)>
```

```
dir(GPT2Tokenizer)
['SPECIAL_TOKENS_ATTRIBUTES',
 '__annotations__',
 '__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_add_tokens',
 '_auto_class',
 '_batch_encode_plus',
 '_batch_prepare_for_model',
 '_build_conversation_input_ids',
 '_convert_id_to_token',
 '_convert_token_to_id',
 '_convert_token_to_id_with_added_voc',
 '_create_or_get_repo',
 '_create_trie',
 '_decode',
 '_encode_plus',
 '_eventual_warn_about_too_long_sequence',
 '_eventually_correct_t5_max_length',
 '_from_pretrained',
 '_get_padding_truncation_strategies',
 '_get_repo_url_from_name',
 '_pad',
 '_push_to_hub',
 '_save_pretrained',
 '_set_processor_class',
 '_tokenize',
 'add_special_tokens',
 'add_tokens',
 'additional_special_tokens',
 'additional_special_tokens_ids',
 'all_special_ids',
 'all_special_tokens',
 'all_special_tokens_extended',
 'as_target_tokenizer',
 'batch_decode',
 'batch_encode_plus',
 'bos_token',
 'bos_token_id',
 'bpe',
 'build_inputs_with_special_tokens',
 'clean_up_tokenization',
 'cls_token',
 'cls_token_id',
 'convert_ids_to_tokens',
 'convert_tokens_to_ids',
 'convert_tokens_to_string',
 'create_token_type_ids_from_sequences',
 'decode',
 'encode',
 'encode_plus',
 'eos_token',
 'eos_token_id',
 'from_pretrained',
 'get_added_vocab',
 'get_special_tokens_mask',
 'get_vocab',
 'is_fast',
 'mask_token',
 'mask_token_id',
 'max_len_sentences_pair',
 'max_len_single_sentence',
 'max_model_input_sizes',
 'model_input_names',
 'num_special_tokens_to_add',
 'pad',
 'pad_token',
 'pad_token_id',
 'pad_token_type_id',
 'padding_side',
 'prepare_for_model',
 'prepare_for_tokenization',
 'prepare_seq2seq_batch',
 'pretrained_init_configuration',
 'pretrained_vocab_files_map',
 'push_to_hub',
 'register_for_auto_class',
 'sanitize_special_tokens',
 'save_pretrained',
 'save_vocabulary',
 'sep_token',
 'sep_token_id',
 'slow_tokenizer_class',
 'special_tokens_map',
 'special_tokens_map_extended',
 'tokenize',
 'truncate_sequences',
 'truncation_side',
 'unk_token',
 'unk_token_id',
 'vocab_files_names',
 'vocab_size']
```

##### (AutoTokenizer) tokenizer

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

inspect.signature(tokenizer)
<Signature (text: Union[str, List[str], List[List[str]]], text_pair: Union[str, List[str], List[List[str]], NoneType] = None, add_special_tokens: bool = True, padding: Union[bool, str, transformers.utils.generic.PaddingStrategy] = False, truncation: Union[bool, str, transformers.tokenization_utils_base.TruncationStrategy] = False, max_length: Optional[int] = None, stride: int = 0, is_split_into_words: bool = False, pad_to_multiple_of: Optional[int] = None, return_tensors: Union[str, transformers.utils.generic.TensorType, NoneType] = None, return_token_type_ids: Optional[bool] = None, return_attention_mask: Optional[bool] = None, return_overflowing_tokens: bool = False, return_special_tokens_mask: bool = False, return_offsets_mapping: bool = False, return_length: bool = False, verbose: bool = True, **kwargs) -> transformers.tokenization_utils_base.BatchEncoding>
```

```
dir(tokenizer)
['SPECIAL_TOKENS_ATTRIBUTES',
 '__annotations__',
 '__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_add_tokens',
 '_additional_special_tokens',
 '_auto_class',
 '_batch_encode_plus',
 '_bos_token',
 '_build_conversation_input_ids',
 '_cls_token',
 '_convert_encoding',
 '_convert_id_to_token',
 '_convert_token_to_id_with_added_voc',
 '_create_or_get_repo',
 '_decode',
 '_decode_use_source_tokenizer',
 '_encode_plus',
 '_eos_token',
 '_eventual_warn_about_too_long_sequence',
 '_eventually_correct_t5_max_length',
 '_from_pretrained',
 '_get_padding_truncation_strategies',
 '_get_repo_url_from_name',
 '_mask_token',
 '_pad',
 '_pad_token',
 '_pad_token_type_id',
 '_processor_class',
 '_push_to_hub',
 '_save_pretrained',
 '_sep_token',
 '_set_processor_class',
 '_tokenizer',
 '_unk_token',
 'add_prefix_space',
 'add_special_tokens',
 'add_tokens',
 'additional_special_tokens',
 'additional_special_tokens_ids',
 'all_special_ids',
 'all_special_tokens',
 'all_special_tokens_extended',
 'as_target_tokenizer',
 'backend_tokenizer',
 'batch_decode',
 'batch_encode_plus',
 'bos_token',
 'bos_token_id',
 'build_inputs_with_special_tokens',
 'can_save_slow_tokenizer',
 'clean_up_tokenization',
 'cls_token',
 'cls_token_id',
 'convert_ids_to_tokens',
 'convert_tokens_to_ids',
 'convert_tokens_to_string',
 'create_token_type_ids_from_sequences',
 'decode',
 'decoder',
 'deprecation_warnings',
 'encode',
 'encode_plus',
 'eos_token',
 'eos_token_id',
 'from_pretrained',
 'get_added_vocab',
 'get_special_tokens_mask',
 'get_vocab',
 'init_inputs',
 'init_kwargs',
 'is_fast',
 'mask_token',
 'mask_token_id',
 'max_len_sentences_pair',
 'max_len_single_sentence',
 'max_model_input_sizes',
 'model_input_names',
 'model_max_length',
 'name_or_path',
 'num_special_tokens_to_add',
 'pad',
 'pad_token',
 'pad_token_id',
 'pad_token_type_id',
 'padding_side',
 'prepare_for_model',
 'prepare_seq2seq_batch',
 'pretrained_init_configuration',
 'pretrained_vocab_files_map',
 'push_to_hub',
 'register_for_auto_class',
 'sanitize_special_tokens',
 'save_pretrained',
 'save_vocabulary',
 'sep_token',
 'sep_token_id',
 'set_truncation_and_padding',
 'slow_tokenizer_class',
 'special_tokens_map',
 'special_tokens_map_extended',
 'tokenize',
 'train_new_from_iterator',
 'truncate_sequences',
 'truncation_side',
 'unk_token',
 'unk_token_id',
 'verbose',
 'vocab',
 'vocab_files_names',
 'vocab_size']
```

##### (AutoTokenizer) tokenizer.encode

```
inspect.signature(tokenizer.encode)
<Signature (text: Union[str, List[str], List[int]], text_pair: Union[str, List[str], List[int], NoneType] = None, add_special_tokens: bool = True, padding: Union[bool, str, transformers.utils.generic.PaddingStrategy] = False, truncation: Union[bool, str, transformers.tokenization_utils_base.TruncationStrategy] = False, max_length: Optional[int] = None, stride: int = 0, return_tensors: Union[str, transformers.utils.generic.TensorType, NoneType] = None, **kwargs) -> List[int]>
```

```
dir(tokenizer.encode)
['__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__func__',
 '__ge__',
 '__get__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__self__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__']
```

##### (Autotokenizer) tokenizer.encode_plus

```
inspect.signature(tokenizer.encode_plus)
<Signature (text: Union[str, List[str], List[int]], text_pair: Union[str, List[str], List[int], NoneType] = None, add_special_tokens: bool = True, padding: Union[bool, str, transformers.utils.generic.PaddingStrategy] = False, truncation: Union[bool, str, transformers.tokenization_utils_base.TruncationStrategy] = False, max_length: Optional[int] = None, stride: int = 0, is_split_into_words: bool = False, pad_to_multiple_of: Optional[int] = None, return_tensors: Union[str, transformers.utils.generic.TensorType, NoneType] = None, return_token_type_ids: Optional[bool] = None, return_attention_mask: Optional[bool] = None, return_overflowing_tokens: bool = False, return_special_tokens_mask: bool = False, return_offsets_mapping: bool = False, return_length: bool = False, verbose: bool = True, **kwargs) -> transformers.tokenization_utils_base.BatchEncoding>
```

```
dir(tokenizer.encode_plus)
['__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__func__',
 '__ge__',
 '__get__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__self__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__']
```

##### AutoConfig

```
model.config
GPT2Config {
  "_name_or_path": "dbmdz/german-gpt2",
  "activation_function": "gelu_new",
  "architectures": [
    "GPT2LMHeadModel"
  ],
  "attn_pdrop": 0.0,
  "bos_token_id": 50256,
  "embd_pdrop": 0.0,
  "eos_token_id": 50256,
  "gradient_checkpointing": false,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "layer_norm_epsilon": 1e-05,
  "model_type": "gpt2",
  "n_ctx": 1024,
  "n_embd": 768,
  "n_head": 12,
  "n_inner": null,
  "n_layer": 12,
  "n_positions": 1024,
  "reorder_and_upcast_attn": false,
  "resid_pdrop": 0.0,
  "scale_attn_by_inverse_layer_idx": false,
  "scale_attn_weights": true,
  "summary_activation": null,
  "summary_first_dropout": 0.1,
  "summary_proj_to_labels": true,
  "summary_type": "cls_index",
  "summary_use_proj": true,
  "task_specific_params": {
    "text-generation": {
      "do_sample": true,
      "max_length": 50
    }
  },
  "torch_dtype": "float32",
  "transformers_version": "4.19.2",
  "use_cache": true,
  "vocab_size": 50265
}
```

#### Example 2: DistilBert

##### DistilBertTokenizer

```
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer

inspect.signature(DistilBertTokenizer)
<Signature (vocab_file, do_lower_case=True, do_basic_tokenize=True, never_split=None, unk_token='[UNK]', sep_token='[SEP]', pad_token='[PAD]', cls_token='[CLS]', mask_token='[MASK]', tokenize_chinese_chars=True, strip_accents=None, **kwargs)>
```

```
dir(DistilBertTokenizer)

['SPECIAL_TOKENS_ATTRIBUTES',
 '__annotations__',
 '__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_add_tokens',
 '_auto_class',
 '_batch_encode_plus',
 '_batch_prepare_for_model',
 '_convert_id_to_token',
 '_convert_token_to_id',
 '_convert_token_to_id_with_added_voc',
 '_create_or_get_repo',
 '_create_trie',
 '_decode',
 '_encode_plus',
 '_eventual_warn_about_too_long_sequence',
 '_eventually_correct_t5_max_length',
 '_from_pretrained',
 '_get_padding_truncation_strategies',
 '_get_repo_url_from_name',
 '_pad',
 '_push_to_hub',
 '_save_pretrained',
 '_set_processor_class',
 '_tokenize',
 'add_special_tokens',
 'add_tokens',
 'additional_special_tokens',
 'additional_special_tokens_ids',
 'all_special_ids',
 'all_special_tokens',
 'all_special_tokens_extended',
 'as_target_tokenizer',
 'batch_decode',
 'batch_encode_plus',
 'bos_token',
 'bos_token_id',
 'build_inputs_with_special_tokens',
 'clean_up_tokenization',
 'cls_token',
 'cls_token_id',
 'convert_ids_to_tokens',
 'convert_tokens_to_ids',
 'convert_tokens_to_string',
 'create_token_type_ids_from_sequences',
 'decode',
 'do_lower_case',
 'encode',
 'encode_plus',
 'eos_token',
 'eos_token_id',
 'from_pretrained',
 'get_added_vocab',
 'get_special_tokens_mask',
 'get_vocab',
 'is_fast',
 'mask_token',
 'mask_token_id',
 'max_len_sentences_pair',
 'max_len_single_sentence',
 'max_model_input_sizes',
 'model_input_names',
 'num_special_tokens_to_add',
 'pad',
 'pad_token',
 'pad_token_id',
 'pad_token_type_id',
 'padding_side',
 'prepare_for_model',
 'prepare_for_tokenization',
 'prepare_seq2seq_batch',
 'pretrained_init_configuration',
 'pretrained_vocab_files_map',
 'push_to_hub',
 'register_for_auto_class',
 'sanitize_special_tokens',
 'save_pretrained',
 'save_vocabulary',
 'sep_token',
 'sep_token_id',
 'slow_tokenizer_class',
 'special_tokens_map',
 'special_tokens_map_extended',
 'tokenize',
 'truncate_sequences',
 'truncation_side',
 'unk_token',
 'unk_token_id',
 'vocab_files_names',
 'vocab_size']
```

##### DistilBertModel

```
dir(DistilBertModel)
['T_destination',
 '__annotations__',
 '__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattr__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setstate__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_apply',
 '_auto_class',
 '_backward_compatibility_gradient_checkpointing',
 '_call_impl',
 '_can_retrieve_inputs_from_name',
 '_convert_head_mask_to_5d',
 '_create_or_get_repo',
 '_expand_inputs_for_generation',
 '_from_config',
 '_get_backward_hooks',
 '_get_backward_pre_hooks',
 '_get_decoder_start_token_id',
 '_get_logits_processor',
 '_get_logits_warper',
 '_get_name',
 '_get_repo_url_from_name',
 '_get_resized_embeddings',
 '_get_resized_lm_head',
 '_get_stopping_criteria',
 '_hook_rss_memory_post_forward',
 '_hook_rss_memory_pre_forward',
 '_init_weights',
 '_keys_to_ignore_on_load_missing',
 '_keys_to_ignore_on_load_unexpected',
 '_keys_to_ignore_on_save',
 '_load_from_state_dict',
 '_load_pretrained_model',
 '_load_pretrained_model_low_mem',
 '_maybe_warn_non_full_backward_hook',
 '_merge_criteria_processor_list',
 '_named_members',
 '_prepare_attention_mask_for_generation',
 '_prepare_decoder_input_ids_for_generation',
 '_prepare_encoder_decoder_kwargs_for_generation',
 '_prepare_input_ids_for_generation',
 '_prepare_model_inputs',
 '_prune_heads',
 '_push_to_hub',
 '_register_load_state_dict_pre_hook',
 '_register_state_dict_hook',
 '_reorder_cache',
 '_replicate_for_data_parallel',
 '_resize_token_embeddings',
 '_save_to_state_dict',
 '_set_default_torch_dtype',
 '_slow_forward',
 '_tie_encoder_decoder_weights',
 '_tie_or_clone_weights',
 '_update_model_kwargs_for_generation',
 '_version',
 'add_memory_hooks',
 'add_module',
 'adjust_logits_during_generation',
 'apply',
 'base_model',
 'base_model_prefix',
 'beam_sample',
 'beam_search',
 'bfloat16',
 'buffers',
 'call_super_init',
 'children',
 'compute_transition_beam_scores',
 'config_class',
 'constrained_beam_search',
 'cpu',
 'create_extended_attention_mask_for_decoder',
 'cuda',
 'device',
 'double',
 'dtype',
 'dummy_inputs',
 'dump_patches',
 'estimate_tokens',
 'eval',
 'extra_repr',
 'float',
 'floating_point_ops',
 'forward',
 'framework',
 'from_pretrained',
 'generate',
 'get_buffer',
 'get_extended_attention_mask',
 'get_extra_state',
 'get_head_mask',
 'get_input_embeddings',
 'get_output_embeddings',
 'get_parameter',
 'get_position_embeddings',
 'get_submodule',
 'gradient_checkpointing_disable',
 'gradient_checkpointing_enable',
 'greedy_search',
 'group_beam_search',
 'half',
 'init_weights',
 'invert_attention_mask',
 'ipu',
 'is_gradient_checkpointing',
 'is_parallelizable',
 'load_state_dict',
 'load_tf_weights',
 'main_input_name',
 'modules',
 'named_buffers',
 'named_children',
 'named_modules',
 'named_parameters',
 'num_parameters',
 'parameters',
 'post_init',
 'prepare_inputs_for_generation',
 'prune_heads',
 'push_to_hub',
 'register_backward_hook',
 'register_buffer',
 'register_for_auto_class',
 'register_forward_hook',
 'register_forward_pre_hook',
 'register_full_backward_hook',
 'register_full_backward_pre_hook',
 'register_load_state_dict_post_hook',
 'register_module',
 'register_parameter',
 'register_state_dict_pre_hook',
 'requires_grad_',
 'reset_memory_hooks_state',
 'resize_position_embeddings',
 'resize_token_embeddings',
 'retrieve_modules_from_names',
 'sample',
 'save_pretrained',
 'set_extra_state',
 'set_input_embeddings',
 'share_memory',
 'state_dict',
 'supports_gradient_checkpointing',
 'tie_weights',
 'to',
 'to_empty',
 'train',
 'type',
 'xpu',
 'zero_grad']
```

```
model.config
DistilBertConfig {
  "_name_or_path": "distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad",
  "activation": "gelu",
  "architectures": [
    "DistilBertForQuestionAnswering"
  ],
  "attention_dropout": 0.1,
  "dim": 768,
  "dropout": 0.1,
  "hidden_dim": 3072,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "max_position_embeddings": 512,
  "model_type": "distilbert",
  "n_heads": 12,
  "n_layers": 6,
  "output_past": true,
  "pad_token_id": 0,
  "qa_dropout": 0.1,
  "seq_classif_dropout": 0.2,
  "sinusoidal_pos_embds": true,
  "tie_weights_": true,
  "transformers_version": "4.19.2",
  "vocab_size": 28996
}
```